# MongoDB Aggregation - How to $lookup with grouped id after $group stage

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Currently, I want to get the data of the 10 users with the latest track using MongoDB. I have some example collections like below:

Users:

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId('642a9621371ad5002f6b7c30'),
        name: 'User 1',
        email: 'user1@example.com',
        password: 'xxxxxxxx',
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('643f6ca47712ec0037cf1f65'),
        name: 'User 2',
        email: 'user2@example.com',
        password: 'xxxxxxxx',
    },
]
```

Tracks:

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId('642d193e1e946b01a7ce86dd'),
        user: ObjectId('642a9621371ad5002f6b7c30'),
        name: 'Electron',
        start: ISODate('2023-03-05T06:46:13.000Z'),
        end: ISODate('2023-03-05T06:46:21.000Z'),
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('642d193e1e946b01a7ce86de'),
        user: ObjectId('643f6ca47712ec0037cf1f65'),
        name: 'Facebook',
        start: ISODate('2023-03-05T04:30:13.000Z'),
        end: ISODate('2023-03-05T04:45:21.000Z'),
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('642d19661e946b01a7ce86ec'),
        user: ObjectId('642a9621371ad5002f6b7c30'),
        name: 'Skype',
        start: ISODate('2023-03-05T01:15:13.000Z'),
        end: ISODate('2023-03-05T02:18:21.000Z'),
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('642d19ac1e946b01a7ce8706'),
        user: ObjectId('643f6ca47712ec0037cf1f65'),
        name: 'Vim',
        start: ISODate('2023-03-05T08:11:13.000Z'),
        end: ISODate('2023-03-05T08:31:21.000Z'),
    },
]
```

Desired data to retrieve:
I will get the list of the latest data tracks and User details of those tracks.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "643f6ca47712ec0037cf1f65",
        "name": "Vim",
        "start": "2023-03-05T08:11:13.000Z",
        "userDetail": [
          {
              _id: ObjectId('643f6ca47712ec0037cf1f65'),
              name: 'User 2',
              email: 'user2@example.com',
          },
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "642a9621371ad5002f6b7c30",
        "name": "Electron",
        "start": "2023-03-05T06:46:13.000Z",
        "userDetail": [
            {
                _id: ObjectId('642a9621371ad5002f6b7c30'),
                name: 'User 1',
                email: 'user1@example.com',
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

Current query, but the output is not as expected:

```
db.tracks.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": { "userId": { "$toString": "$_id" }}},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$user",
        "name": { "$last": "$name" },
        "start": { "$last": "$start" },
    }},
    { "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "user",
      "foreignField": "userId",
      "as": "userDetail"
    }}
    ,
    { "$sort": { "start": -1 } },
])
```

Current data being received:
It is getting all the users in the collection

```
[
    {
        "_id": "643f6ca47712ec0037cf1f65",
        "name": "Vim",
        "start": "2023-03-05T08:11:13.000Z",
        "userDetail": [
          {
              _id: ObjectId('643f6ca47712ec0037cf1f65'),
              name: 'User 2',
              email: 'user2@example.com',
          },
          {
            _id: ObjectId('642a9621371ad5002f6b7c30'),
            name: 'User 1',
            email: 'user1@example.com',
          },
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "642a9621371ad5002f6b7c30",
        "name": "Electron",
        "start": "2023-03-05T06:46:13.000Z",
        "userDetail": [
            {
                _id: ObjectId('643f6ca47712ec0037cf1f65'),
                name: 'User 2',
                email: 'user2@example.com',
            },
            {
              _id: ObjectId('642a9621371ad5002f6b7c30'),
              name: 'User 1',
              email: 'user1@example.com',
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

Hope to help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues**

1. After the `$group` stage, there is no `user` field.
2. For the foreign field, there is no `userId` field.

Your `$lookup` stage should be as below:

```
{
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "userDetail"
  }
}
```

For me, the `addFields` stage seems not needed.

The complete query would be:

```
db.tracks.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user",
      "name": {
        "$last": "$name"
      },
      "start": {
        "$last": "$start"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "userDetail"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "start": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "userDetail.password"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3lvtMtDMz1b)

Comment: Also do you know how to paginate it?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. For pagination, you may use [`skip`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [`limit`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) stages.